# ℤₚ Forming a Finite Field [SOLVED]

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

It is my understanding that since $ℤ_p$ (the integers mod p) is a commutative ring, $ℤ_p$ is a finite field if there exists a multiplicative inverse element for all elements of $ℤ_p$.

i.e. $∃x$ such that $∀$ $a∈ℤ_p, ax=1$

which is true if $ax = py +1 $ (for some $y∈ℤ$, because that's how modular arithmetic works)

therefore $ax - py = 1$, which is true because of Bezout's Identity and since $gcd(a,p)=1$.

Therefore there exists an integer, $x$, such that $ax=1\space(mod\space p)$

I understand all of this (and assume it's all correct), but I don't understand why it must be the case that $x$ is an element of $ℤ_p$, since it has to be in order for it to be the inverse element. (i.e. why is it necessarily the case that $0<x<p-1$)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Multiplicative *inverse* not identity. We don't care that $x < p$, it is the integers $\bmod p$ ie. $x$ and $x+kp$ represent the same element.

Comment: A field is a commutative ring with identity in which ever **nonzero** element has a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Also, you have the quantifiers reversed. It's not "there is an $a$ such that for every [nonzero] $x$", it is "for every nonzero $x$ there is an $a$."

Comment: You are confusing elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ and elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p$. The latter are *equivalence classes* of elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, where the equivalence relation is $a\sim b$ iff $a\equiv b\mod{p}$. So while it is true that the $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ that you find may not satisfy $0 < x < p$, its equivalence class still lies in $\mathbb{Z}/p$, and in fact you can find a (unique) integer $x'$ satisfying $0 < x' < p$ such that $x\equiv x'\mod{p}$.

Comment: @rogerl , thank you very much, that is exactly what I needed

Comment: @reuns , thank you, that makes sense